# How do I stop the value from refreshing?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and trying to make a basic mock savings account interface for a college assignment, but when I subtract an amount of money from the balance of 500, it will refresh again when I subtract again. For example, if I withdraw 10 I will have 490, then if I withdraw 5 it will take away from 500 and I will have 495 again. How so I retain the value?
Here is the code:

```
namespace Savings_Account
{
    public partial class Menu : Form
    {
        public Menu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txtBalance.Text = Convert.ToString("£" + dBalance);
            grpWithdraw.Enabled = false;
        }

        decimal dBalance = 500;
        decimal dWithdraw;

        private void txtPin_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtPin.Text == "1234")
        {
            grpWithdraw.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void btnWithdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!decimal.TryParse(txtWithdraw.Text, out dWithdraw))
        {
            txtWithdraw.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("An invalid character has been entered");
        }
        else
        {
            txtBalance.Text = "£" + (dBalance - dWithdraw).ToString();
            txtWithdraw.Clear();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What platform is this - WinForms, ASP.NET?

Comment: @n8wrl: That doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: don't use tags in your title...

Comment: @xbonez: If this was asp.net then every time he hit his page dBalance would be reset to 500. If it was winforms, the form class would be alive as long as it was running and this wouldn't happen.

Comment: @n8wrl: Fair enough. That makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

Do the math using the variable dBalance

```
   dBalance = dBalance - dWithdraw;
   txtBalance.Text = "£" + dBalance.ToString();
```

In this way the variable `dBalance` will be updated at every withdraw.

Perhaps it is a bit early to worry about it, but a test to check if you have enough money should be mandatory

```
  if(dBalance - dWithdraw > 0)
  {
      dBalance = dBalance - dWithdraw;
      txtBalance.Text = "£" + dBalance.ToString();
  }
  else
      MessageBox.Show("Not enough funds!");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
txtBalance.Text = "£" + (dBalance - dWithdraw).ToString();
```

You are always subtracting from `dBalance` which is always 500. What you should instead do is save the new value in `dBalance`:

```
dBalance = dBalance - dWithdraw
txtBalance.Text = "£" + dBalance.ToString();
```

Ideally, instead of doing the subtraction there, create a method called `doWithdraw()` or something, and do the calculation there. You will need to add checks to ensure balance doesn't go negative (unless you allow overdrafting) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating dBalance anyplace.  You're only updating txtBalance, but each time you do the withdraw call you compute the new value based on dBalance again.